# Can I compile all projects and dependencies into a single .exe in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Windows Forms application that installs its own prerequisites via a UI (a bit like InstallShield, or similar, might) before being usable. My application, as it stands, consists of two projects, one of which contains folders, which contain the prerequisite bits of software, which I install, quietly, using the command line, after checking whether or not they're already on the target machine.

What I'd really like to do is compile both projects and all of the third-party executables into a single executable. Can it be done? I'm open to "self-extractor" suggestions, but I don't know where to start with these in Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, but this might be of interest: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That led me on to using IExpress, which didn't quite fit my needs, but I zipped all of my dependencies up into an archive, and wrote a little Console app that IExpress launches when it starts to unzip everything and launch my Windows Forms exe.